# Create,Delete and Update not working in Kendo Grid using ADO.Net

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ado.net, kendo-grid

I have created kendo grid in mvc. So far the create,update delete actions are not working.

(This project is just for practice.)

The codes are below

**Model: Student.cs**

```
public class Student
    {
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StudentSubject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int StudentMarks { get; set;}
    
    }
```

DAL:

IStudentAccess.cs

```
public interface IStudentAccess
    {
        List<Student> GetStudents();

        Student GetStudentByID(int ID);

        Student CreateStudent(Student objStudent);

        Student UpdateStudent(Student objStudent);

        Student DeleteStudent(int ID);
    }
```

StudentAccess.cs

```
public class StudentAccess : IStudentAccess
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;
        public StudentAccess(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            List<Student> lstStudents = new List<Student>();
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStudents", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Student objStudent = new Student();

                        objStudent.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["StudentID"]);
                        objStudent.StudentName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["StudentName"]);
                        objStudent.StudentSubject = Convert.ToString(dataReader["StudentSubject"]);
                        objStudent.StudentMarks = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["StudentMarks"]);

                        lstStudents.Add(objStudent);
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            return lstStudents;
        }
        public Student GetStudentByID(int ID)
        {
            Student objStudent = new Student();
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStudentByID", connection);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnID", ID);
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        objStudent.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["StudentID"]);
                        objStudent.StudentName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["StudentName"]);
                        objStudent.StudentSubject = Convert.ToString(dataReader["StudentSubject"]);
                        objStudent.StudentMarks = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["StudentMarks"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    dataReader.Close();
                }
            }
            return objStudent;
        }
        public Student CreateStudent(Student objStudent)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand createCmd = new SqlCommand("spCreateStudent", connection);
                createCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                createCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tcName", objStudent.StudentName);
                createCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnPrice", objStudent.StudentSubject);
                createCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnQuantity", objStudent.StudentMarks);

                connection.Open();
                createCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            return objStudent;
        }
        public Student UpdateStudent(Student objStudent)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Check if the item exists
                SqlCommand checkCmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStudentByID", connection);
                checkCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                checkCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnID", objStudent.StudentID);
                connection.Open();
                var reader = checkCmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (!reader.Read())
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    return null;
                }
                reader.Close();
                //If Item is found
                SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("spUpdateStudent", connection);
                updateCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnID", objStudent.StudentID);
                updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tcName", objStudent.StudentName);
                updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tcSubject", objStudent.StudentSubject);
                updateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnMarks", objStudent.StudentMarks);


                updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            return objStudent;
        }
        public Student DeleteStudent(int ID)
        {
            string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //Check if the item exists
                SqlCommand checkCmd = new SqlCommand("spGetStudentByID", connection);
                checkCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                checkCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnID", ID);
                connection.Open();
                var reader = checkCmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (!reader.Read())
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    return null;
                }
                reader.Close();

                //if item is found
                SqlCommand deleteCmd = new SqlCommand("spDeleteStudent", connection);
                deleteCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                deleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tnID", ID);
                deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

StudentsController.cs

(Is this the correct way of writing)

```
public class StudentsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IStudentAccess objStudentAccess;
        public StudentsController(IStudentAccess studentAccess)
        {
            objStudentAccess = studentAccess;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public JsonResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var students = objStudentAccess.GetStudents();
            return Json(students.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
     
        public JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Student objStudent)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                objStudentAccess.CreateStudent(objStudent);

            }
            return Json(new[] {objStudent}.ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));
        }

        public JsonResult Delete([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,Student objStudent)
        {
            objStudentAccess.DeleteStudent(objStudent.StudentID);
            return Json(new[] { objStudent }.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }
```

Kendo Grid: Index.cshtml

```
@using TelerikStudent.Models;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@(
Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentID).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentName).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentSubject).Width(100);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentMarks).Width(100);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(100);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar=>toolbar.Create())
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource=>dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.StudentID);
            model.Field(p => p.StudentID).Editable(false);
        })
        .Create(create=>create.Action("Create","Students"))
        .Read(read=>read.Action("Read","Students"))
        .Update(update=>update.Action("Update","Students"))
        .Destroy(destroy=>destroy.Action("Destroy","Students"))
    )
)
```

I'm not sure if I made any simple mistakes. Any clarifications will be helpful. In order to check the update and delete actions I had to manually enter data in database.

Output:
[image: Output]